# Spring Integration JSON to Object with @Valid

Tags: spring-integration

I have a use case where I am receiving a `json` on a `channel` that is transformed to a `DTO` using inbuilt `Transformers.fromJson(MyDTO.class)`.

The DTO has `javax.validation` annotations. How can I trigger the validations?

One way is write a `validator` class and call `validate(MyDTO myDTO`) after the transformation? Is there an inbuilt support for such uses cases to trigger `javax.validations` during transformation step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is the way to register custom `IntegrationContextUtils.MESSAGE_HANDLER_FACTORY_BEAN_NAME` bean of `DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory` with a validator and have then a `@ServiceActivator` with a `@Validated` (`@Valid`) annotation on your `MyDTO` payload argument, but I feel this is going to be a bit cumbersome.

Consider to implement some `GenericSelector` which is going to perform a `Validator.validate()` for a payload to be used from the `filter()` EI-method.

We still have an opened ticket to implement something out-of-the-box: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4068